# How do I move a music collection

Tags: itunes

Sorry for what must be a very simple question but how would I move all the tunes I have on my laptop to an external drive connected to the laptop.  Storage has become an issue and the laptop is quickly running out of space so I want to put all my tunes on an external and free up some space.  This would not be for a backup but to free up space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty straighforward, the steps are essentially:

- Open iTunes and consolidate your existing library (File > Library > Organise Library)
- Quit iTunes
- Copy your ~/Music/iTunes folder to the external drive
- Open iTunes while holding down the Alt key, which will prompt you to select the new library
- When you're sure it's working, delete your original library.

For more details on each step, see [this iMore article](https://www.imore.com/how-move-your-itunes-library-external-hard-drive). And as always, make sure you have a working backup before you start.